# Example of restricted Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples

I came across the following example of a restricted Lie algebra in the book [Frobenius Algebras I](https://ems.press/books/etb/105) by Skowroński and Yamagata.

Given a field $K$ of characteristic $p > 0$, a **restricted Lie algebra** over $K$ is a triple $(L, [-, -], {}^{[p]})$ where $(L, [-, -])$ is a Lie algebra over $K$ and ${}^{[p]}$ is a (set-theoretic) map $L \to L, x \mapsto x^{[p]}$ satisfying certain conditions (See page 580 of the above book, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Lie_algebra#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20restricted%20Lie%20algebra%20is%20a,where%20the%20p%20operation%20is%20the%20identity%20map.), or [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172031/restricted-lie-algebras-definition) for details).

The first example (Example 2.21 (a)) of a restricted Lie algebra over $K$ is constructed as follows:

> Let $L = K^2$ and $e_1 = (1, 0)$, $e_2 = (0, 1)$ be the canonical basis of $L$ over $K$. Consider the $K$-bilinear map $[-, -] \colon L \times L \to L$ given by $$[e_1, e_1] = 0, \quad [e_2, e_2] = 0, \quad [e_1, e_2] = e_2, \quad [e_2, e_1] = -e_2,$$ and the map ${}^{[p]} \colon L \to L$ given by $x^{[p]} = \lambda_1^pe_1$ for $x = \lambda_1e_1 + \lambda_2e_2 \in L$.

I doubt this defines a restricted Lie algebra. One property that the triple $(L, [-, -], {}^{[p]})$ must satisfy (except for $(L, [-, -])$ being a Lie algebra) is that $\operatorname{ad}{(x^{[p]})} = (\operatorname{ad}{x}) ^ p$ for all $x \in L$, where for $z \in L$, $\operatorname{ad}{z} \, \colon L \to L$ denotes the morphism $y \mapsto [z, y]$.
However, for example when $p = 3$, we have
$$\operatorname{ad}((e_1 + e_2)^{[3]})(e_1) = \operatorname{ad}(e_1)(e_1) = [e_1, e_1] = 0.$$
Meanwhile,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{ad}(e_1 + e_2)(e_1) & = [e_1 + e_2, e_1] = [e_1, e_1] + [e_2, e_1] = -e_2; \\
\operatorname{ad}(e_1 + e_2)(e_2) & = [e_1 + e_2, e_2] = [e_1, e_2] + [e_2, e_2] = e_2,
\end{align}$$
gives
$$\operatorname{ad}(e_1 + e_2)^3(e_1)
= -\operatorname{ad}(e_1 + e_2)^2(e_2)
= -\operatorname{ad}(e_1 + e_2)(e_2)
= -e_2.$$
Hence $\operatorname{ad}((e_1 + e_2)^{[3]}) \ne \operatorname{ad}(e_1 + e_2)^3$.

Are there something wrong in my calculation? I would also like to know if slight modification turns this (seemingly non-)example into an example of a restricted Lie algebra.

Comment: you're correct - it should have been $x^{[p]} = \lambda_2^p e_2$. Your example is the subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ with basis $(1/2)h, e$, where the $p$th power map is just the ordinary $p$th power of matrices (so that $h^3=h, e^3 = 0$. $e_1$ is $h/2 = \begin{pmatrix}1/2&0\\0&-1/2\end{pmatrix}$ and $e_2$ is $e = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ (I may have made a sign error somewhere but it can be fixed, if necessary by transposing $e$)

Comment: @MatthewTowers Thank you for the clear answer! I have checked that when $p = 3$, we indeed have an injective morphism $f \colon L \to \mathfrak{g}_2(K)$ of Lie algebras sending $e_1$ to $h/2$ and $e_2$ to $e$ since $[h, e] = 2e$. However, for $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in K$, it seems that $f((\lambda_1e_1 + \lambda_2e_2)^{[3]}) = f(\lambda_2^3e_2) = \lambda_2^3e$ does not coincide with $f(\lambda_1e_1 + \lambda_2e_2)^3$, which (as long as my calculation is correct) is $\lambda_1^2 f(\lambda_1e_1 + \lambda_2e_2)$.

Comment: I think @MatthewTowers' idea works but only if we identify $e_1$ with $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ instead.